# Trouble transitioning from Entity Framework query to NHibernate

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc-4, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I am attempting to teach myself NHibernate after working exclusively with Entity Framework for a few years now. I know how I would write the query, and I know how I would write the code with EF and lambda expressions, but translating that to NHibernate is stumping me.

The query would be written as:

```
SELECT fb.*
FROM foo f
INNER JOIN bar b ON f.fooid = b.fooid
INNER JOIN foobar fb ON b.barid = fb.barid
WHERE f.otherid = 1
```

Basically, I know a key of my start table (`foo`), and I want to return all of the matching rows in the 2nd joined table (`foobar`). In EF, I would write:

```
public IEnumerable<foobar> GetFooBarInfo(int intFooID)
{
    return db.foo.Include(f => f.bar)
                 .Include(fb => fb.bar.foobar)
                 .Where(f => f.otherentity.fooid == intFooID)
                 .Select(fb => fb.bar.foobar)
                 .ToList();
}
```

Now converting that to NHibernate is where I need help. I have tried a few things, none of which I've saved, but the latest version returns 1 row instead of 7 rows. It looks like it is returning the one row in `foobar` where `barid = 1` instead of all `barid` values where `fooid = 1`.

```
public IEnumerable<foobar> GetFooBarInfo(int intFooID)
{
    foo f = null;
    bar b = null;
    foobar fb = null;

    return db.QueryOver<foo>(() => f)
             .Where(fi => fi.otherentity.fooid == intFooID)
             .Inner.JoinQueryOver(ba => ba.bar, () => b)
             .Inner.JoinQueryOver(fbar => fbar.foobar, () => fb)
             .Select(Projections.ProjectionList()
                                .Add(Projections.Property(() => fb.barid))
                                .Add(Projections.Property(() => fb.barname))
                                .Add(Projections.Property(() => fb.bardescription))
                    )
             .TransformUsing(Transformers.AliasToBean<foobar>())
             .List<foobar>();
}
```

I also just realized that it isn't truly filling the projection/transform. `barid` is 0 and `barname` and `bardescription` are null - these obviously have values in the database.

Comment: Your transcription into QueryOver seems to be ok. The only exception to this is the Projecton part. you should project `fb.barid` instead of `f.barid`, to follow the upper part in LINQ...

Comment: @RadimKöhler I apologize...that was a typo.

Comment: Any reason why NHibernate LINQ didn't work?

Comment: @OskarBerggren - I explained it, to the best of my understanding, in my answer. I still don't know why it populated null results until I added the string alias.

Comment: You are talking about QueryOver. I don't see to mentioning using _LINQ_ with NHibernate anywhere. Hint: Apply `using NHibernate.Linq;` and then `session.Query()...`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was attempting to join `foo` and `bar` on `fooid`, but `bar` had its own primary key `foobarid`. Once I turned on logging for NHibernate, I could see the **generated 
query was incorrect**. It was generating:

```
SELECT fb.*
FROM foo f
INNER JOIN bar b ON f.fooid = b.foobarid
INNER JOIN foobar fb ON b.barid = fb.barid
WHERE f.otherid = 1
```

So then I realized I needed to include the parent table for `bar`, which was `baz` in order to get the join right. But this meant I needed to make the map for 
`baz` include:

```
.HasMany(x => x.bar).KeyColumn("fooid")
.HasMany(x => x.foobar).KeyColumn("barid")
```

Then alter the `QueryOver` to include this additional table. This got the result count right, but still wasn't projecting into the object properly - everything was null 
until I added the string alias on each `Projection.Property()`:

```
public IEnumerable<foobar> GetFooBarInfo(int intFooID)
{
    foo f = null;
    bar b = null;
    baz bz = null;
    foobar fb = null;

    return db.QueryOver<foo>(() => f)
             .Where(fi => fi.otherentity.fooid == intFooID)
             .Inner.JoinQueryOver(bb => bb.baz, () => bz)
             .Inner.JoinQueryOver(ba => ba.bar, () => b)
             .Inner.JoinQueryOver(fbar => fbar.foobar, () => fb)
             .Select(Projections.ProjectionList()
                      .Add(Projections.Property(() => fb.barid), "barid")
                      .Add(Projections.Property(() => fb.barname), "barname")
                      .Add(Projections.Property(() => fb.bardescription), "bardescription")
             )
             .TransformUsing(Transformers.AliasToBean<foobar>())
             .List<foobar>();
}
```